# How to add the first cell value with the second cell value in the same column and display result in next column in gridview

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a gridview in asp.net with backend sql. I need to add the first cell value with the second cell value in the same column and display result in next column.
 Eg: sql table:

```
                   NO  Item    TYPE        QTY
                    1  glass   Transfer     2
                    2  glass   Invoice     -1
                    3  glass   Transfer     4
```

and I need to display the result as

```
                     NO   Item    TYPE    QTY    Balance

                      1   glass  Transfer  2      2
                      2   glass  Invoice  -1      1
                      3   glass  Transfer  4      5
```

I need to add the 4th column first cell with 2nd cell and display result in 5th column.
 Pls help.

Comment: Which version of which database are you using? Is the data really sorted by **NO**?

Comment: Where is the **pen** in your expected result coming from? -- And **-1 + 4 = 3** whilst you seem to expect **5**.

Comment: no, its also glass, database using is sql 2008, I need to add the first cell and second cell in the column and display the result in the next column,like I displayed in the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you *described* could be done as follows:

```
SELECT
  no
  , item
  , type
  , qty
  , qty + LAG (qty, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY no) balance
FROM SomeTable
ORDER BY no
;
```

This, however, is not in line with your expected result, which looks rather like the output of:

```
SELECT
  no
  , item
  , type
  , qty
  , SUM (qty) OVER (ORDER BY no ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) balanceExample
FROM SomeTable
ORDER BY no
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4cde/1)

**Update:**
As the SQL Server being used by the OP is version 2008, the analytic functions `LAG` and `SUM` are not available. In that case the following approach might help:

```
SELECT
  S1.no
  , S1.item
  , S1.type
  , S1.qty
  , SUM(S2.qty) balanceExample
FROM SomeTable S1
INNER JOIN SomeTable S2
  ON S2.no <= S1.no
GROUP BY S1.no, S1.item, S1.type, S1.qty
ORDER BY S1.no
;
```

Updated [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4cde/2).

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: Sir, while executing it shows error as                      LAG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Where are you getting this error? The sample [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4cde/1) does employ **MS SQL Server 2008**, and runs nicely. And you seemed to have indicated to be using the same database version.

Comment: Sir LAG function is not support in sqlserver 2008,Lag and lead is not supporting.Is there any another method to achieve this

Comment: Is there any way I can do this in gridview in asp.net.

Comment: I have tried like this, but it shows error                                                       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            total = total + Convert.ToDouble(GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[6].Text);
            //Label2.Text = total.ToString();
            //Label2.Text = GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[6].Text;
            GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[7].Text = total.ToString();
        }

Comment: Sorry for relying on SQL Fiddle instead of checking the actual documentation. I'll check for a way to mimic the functionality with what is actually available in SQL Server 2008. Unfortunately, I don't have appropriate GridView experience to contribute. When you look at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4cde/1) - do we need to re-build **balanceDescribed** or **balanceExample**?

Comment: @vishnusuresh Did you have a chance to check the update for its applicability in your environment?

Comment: Thank you sir for your help, I have done the above using c# code in gridview,